# Drupal 8 track counter value

Tags: drupal, state, drupal-8

In my Drupal website I would like to manage a counter that is increased when a certain entity is saved. I thought Drupal::state would be a good way to do this, since it is stored in the database and this is kind of a state value. My basic process is:

```
function hook_entity_presave($entity) {
    $value = \Drupal::state()->get('my_counter');
    \Drupal::state()->set('my_counter', $value + 1);
}
```

With multiple users however I noticed this doesn't work well. The entity is saved more than the counter is increased. Of course this could happen if the function is called so often that multiple get queries are executed simultaneously before the set queries are executed, but I expect that not to happen to quickly (if there is a simple single query update function I'm very interested though!).

The issue seems to be that Drupal::state manages its own local cache of values. So `get` might not return the actual value, but rather a cached value.

The solution would be:

```
function hook_entity_presave($entity) {
    \Drupal::state()->resetCache();
    $value = \Drupal::state()->get('my_counter');
    \Drupal::state()->set('my_counter', $value + 1);
}
```

However, this feels very inefficient, as I'm resetting the cache potentially hundreds of times per minute, and I only need to clear the specific cache value, not all cache values.

So my question is: Is there a better way to keep track of a counter value?

Comment: Can the update run soon after the save but not immediately? You could look at creating a QueueWorker. Items run in sequence (often with cron), should not have cache issues. I'm not familiar with State, so not sure how this would work with QueueWorkers. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Annotation%21QueueWorker.php/class/QueueWorker/8.2.x

Comment: What is the use case? Do you need to have a global counter, or do you need to have a counter based on entities? Using a simple thing as a new field that increases on the entity upon saving wouldn't work? Also you could use a count on these if you want a global counter for all the entities and how many times they were saved.